# measuring how much signal corrupted by passing from a medium

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals

I am looking for a measure to report how much a signal has corrupted by passing a medium.

Suppose we have a signal `2Hz` and amplitude `1`. I pass it from a medium. A receiver got the signal with 2Hz, amplitude 0.5 and a few more signals.
Convolution gives me an array that say with a specific delay overlapping between input and output is maximum. 
Do we have a measure to report a single scalar how much a signal has corrupted?

Comment: Signal corruption is a vague term. How do you define it?

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP!  As Deve says, you need to define what you mean by corruption (noise) for your particular application.  I'm closing this until you [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/41472/edit) to supply this information, or state some general concerns about corruption. See Fat32's answer, and let us know whether this gives you what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

The most typical measure of a signal corruption (or degradation) would be an error squarred integral (or sum for discrete case), preferably normalized such as:

$$ \epsilon = \frac {\int (x(t)-x_r(t))^2 dt}{\int (x(t))^2 dt} $$

Where $x_r(t)$ is identified as the received and corrupted signal. The interval of integration choosen to fit into signal duration of interest.

This is an unweighted (or equiweighted) calculation. If you think that certain features of the error is more impotrant, more relevant, more effective than the others, then you could reflect this by modifications such as simple linear weighting or onlinear processing of the error accordingly, which would produce more meaningful results.